# Is atomic_compare_exchange_weak preferable over the strong version even in a long loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

Suppose I use CAS inside a loop that contains a number of operations other than the CAS. The loop runs until the CAS succeeds. Should I use the weak version of CAS? Or will it be non cost effective to redo all the loop's operations in case the CAS spuriously fail, and I'd better use the strong version of CAS to ensure repeating the loop only if the CAS really had to fail (because `object` != `expected`)? Or is there no theoretical answer and I should try both versions and compare their performance?

Comment: That depends on your loop body, the machine you are running on, your compiler and what other code is accessing that variable. So yes, the answer is you probably have to measure. May I ask to see an example? Usually strong and weak exchange are not simply interchangeable.

Comment: Btw.: Before measuring you should check the assembler code. Both versions might actually generate the exact same instructions.